# Grid layout and UL weird margin

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have an unordered list with display: grid, whenever I go to mobile view on chrome devtools the grid changes to be 1 item in a column instead of 5. Until here everything is fine but I get some weird left margin that I haven't defined anywhere in my code and I don't understand why it's here.. When I set margin:0 for the ul it's still there.. any idea?

[image: Weird left margin]

[image: Weird left margin]

[image: When margin is set to 0 it still appears]

My css & html:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 5%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 20% 20% 20%;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.title2 {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  ul {
    width: 300px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: 280px;
  }
}
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 90%;
  height: 320px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5% 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .card {
    height: 265px;
  }
}

<div class="card">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img class="product-thumbnail" src="assets/products/{{product.image}}" alt="{{product.name}}" title="{{product.name}}">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title4 product-name"><strong>{{product.name}}</strong></div>
    <div class="product-price">{{product.price}} $</div>
    <p>
      <button class="btn-purchase" (click)="purchaseItem()">Purchase</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="title2">Products:</div>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let product of products"><app-product [product]="product"></app-product></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: have you resetted it the `body`s `margin` to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside media queries set the `left`/`right` `margin` of the `.card` to `auto` to center it horizontally:

```
.card {
  margin: 5% auto;
}
```

I'd also recommend to use the basic CSS browser reset like this:

```
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}
html, body {width:100%}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have given ul a margin-right:10px only on small screen i.e 480px  its going to take other margins from larger screen if defined.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
ul {
    width: 300px;
    margin:5% 0;
    grid-template-columns: 280px;
  }
```

or if you also want to give margin-right:10px on small screen than

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
ul {
    width: 300px;
    margin:5% 10px 5% 0;
    grid-template-columns: 280px;
  }
```